# Where can I get add-ins for visual studio express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

There is countless add-ins on  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ but it seems they are all not for visual studio express (I use visual studio 2010 C# express in my laptop).

But extension manager does provide links to the site so I wonder how can I add-ins for VS express in the site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio Express does not support add-ins.

If you are student, you may be able to get full version (Professional) from either [MSDN AA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic/bb250591) or from [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/). Otherwise you are out of luck (unless you purchase it yourself).

EDIT: You may also try [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/). It is open-source alternative to Visual Studio. It does not support Visual Studio extensions, but it does support its own extensions. And it may have the features you are looking for.

EDIT Dec 2014: There is now a [Visual Studio Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) which is free for noncommercial and some commerical uses and **does** support add-ins!