# AnkhSVN doesn't integrate with visual c# express 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I wanted to use a particle system in a kinect project with c sharp . and I found flint particle at http://code.google.com/p/flint-sharp/ .seems it uses svn . I've previously worked with SVNs with eclipse . now I want to use it in my visual c# express 2010, and it seems I should use tortoiseSVN and ankhSVN . I installed both and from the tutorials there should be a tab at tools>options>source control , but there's no such tab . 
 I'll be appreciated if anyone can help me with this . tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

express edition just does not support add-ins.

[Where can I get add-ins for visual studio express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953030/where-can-i-get-add-ins-for-visual-studio-express)

Comment: yup its annoying but its one of the drawbacks of using the express tools, no resharper meant no use express for me. Thats just life unfortunately

Comment: so there's no way for me to use SVNs in my visual c# project?

Comment: You don't need a plugin to use SVN. You can use Tortoise SVN or another SVN client. You just can't have it integrated into the IDE which doesn't give a great deal of extra convenience / functionality.