# Visual Studio Community Community Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, licensing

I would like to know if the Visual Studio Community's license can be used to develop a "community" system to use in a religious institution.

None of us will use it for profit, it will be only for Community usage. We will be in a team of three workers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requests legal/licensing guidance

Comment: You should have read the info on the tag you're using: [tag:licensing]

Answer (score 2):

You can be able to use Visual Studio Community edition for both personal and some commercial development(and yes for creating a community application). The reason Microsoft released the community edition was because developers couldn't install 3rd party extensions in the Express editions.Read more  below

[accepted answer shows the shortcomings of Express edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953030/where-can-i-get-add-ins-for-visual-studio-express)

[and this article too](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/05/21/no-extensions-for-visual-studio-express.aspx)

Comment: thank you, but I'm still unsure if I have a problem